# How to use =VLOOKUP under these circumstances?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, vlookup

So I know how to use =VLOOKUP when you are searching for a single value within a cell, but I'm not sure how to do it when I have a range, ex. say the cells value is 1-5, the next is 5-10.

[image]

This is the table I have that I'm trying to search. The normal formula won't work for me, I just get the #N/A error. Am I using the wrong search function?

Comment: If you know you'll only have integers, you could just make your lookup table have separate rows for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc . . . your current use case is small enough that this wouldn't be too difficult . . . hundreds of records may make this more difficult

Comment: @ernie I know, but I need it to be the way it is.

Comment: You could split your range into min/max, and then use the min column to match on . . . by default, VLOOKUP will look for an exact match, or "[the next largest value that is less than the lookup_value](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HA102752820.aspx)" . . . if you need something else, you're going to need to clarify your question.

Comment: @ernie like I said can't reformat the lookup table. Am I using the wrong function then?

Comment: If you can't change the lookup table at all, can you use some cells under your control to refer to that "readonly" cells, and then modify your new cells so that you can perform a `vlookup`?

Comment: @KenL Nope. It's an assignment so it has to be done that way. Oddly enough we never went over any circumstances like this in class. Nothing in the text book either. Can't find anything online neither. Odd.

Comment: If it's an assignment I'm pretty sure that what @ernie said was correct. *1-5, 6-10, 21 or more* are text, while 1,2,3... are integers.  `VLOOKUP` simply cannot compare integers to text.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your lookup value is in I2:

```
=VLOOKUP(IF(I2<=5, "1-5", IF(I2<=10, "6-10", IF(I2<=20, "'11-20", "21 or more"))),B2:C5,2,TRUE)
```

Except, in my Excel, it refuses to treat that 11-20 as text, and calls it a 'Text Date with 2-digit year'.  Because of this, the formula doesn't work for 11-20.  I'm going to leave the 90% solution in case someone knows a fix for the 'text is a 2-digit year' problem.

Comment: Note, this formula does work for 11-20 if you do Data->Text to Columns and force column B in as truly simple text.  No way to know if OP screen shot is truly text or not.

Comment: huh. i tried that with no joy. will give it another shot tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

This will work, if the number you're looking up is in cell `C1` and your table starts in `A1`

```
=VLOOKUP(IF(C1>20,"21 or more",IF(C1>10,"11-20",IF(C1>5,"6-10",IF(C1>0,"1-5",0)))),$A$1:$B$4,2,0)
```

You nest the `if`s from greatest to smallest to catch with the least amount of tests, then assign the text for the `vlookup`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this, I'd add a column for min, based on the ranges, e.g.:

```
=IF(SEARCH(" ", A3), LEFT(A3,SEARCH(" ",A3)-1), LEFT(A3,SEARCH("-",A3)-1))
```

Then you can use a vlookup based on the new minimum column since VLOOKUP by default will look for an exact match, or "the next largest value that is less than the lookup_value"

The other answers with the multiple nested IF()'s match your criteria as well, but if the assignment is to really come up with something like that, then it's teaching some really bad ideas.

Using a bunch of nested IF() statements, then feeding that to a VLOOKUP() is convoluted and absurd.  You've hard-coded the bounds into the formula, and the VLOOKUP() adds almost nothing (the value substitution could happen right at the IF() level).